# What does the front page mean?

Tags: support, flags, spam, offensive, homepage

I am looking at the question which is "[What are the spam and offensive flags, and how do they work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58032/what-are-the-spam-and-offensive-flags-and-how-do-they-work/58035#58035)". And it says that when a post accrued 3 flags (spam or offensive), it will be banished from the front page. What does the front page mean?

Comment: What's the true context? Have you never been to another site's front page?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Home_page

Comment: Does the front page mean the home page?

Comment: Yes, front page is another term for home page.

Comment: @JasonC No. The rule mentioned in the question maybe applies to all the sites of SE.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The front page is quite literally (as of now) the page you see when you first load a site. Internally, we're expanding that definition, where we consider any page that people commonly visit in order to find new stuff to answer to be the 'front page'. You might to go /questions, you might to go a certain tag feed - whatever, it's the first thing you see when you open the site looking for stuff to do.

Things we're currently working on entail making sure that you don't see awful stuff in those places (wherever they might be), while still leaving you the ability to drill down into it *if* you really want to. This would affect not only stuff that has been heavily down-voted and / or flagged, but also stuff that the system identifies as being of questionable quality. Some of this is in place now.

In short, starting soon, the 'front page' is whatever page users show as being the most visible on the site, based on behavior we examine when watching how folks find new questions to answer.

The spirit of it, to keep in mind (as [Rose Red](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rose_Red_%28miniseries%29) continues to build upon itself) is *we don't want to put crap in your face when you first hit the site, unless you really want to see crap in order to help deal with it*.

Comment: Can I use your quote? It's brilliant! :D

Comment: Which quote .... ?

Comment: "*we don't want to put crap in your face when you first hit the site, unless you really want to see crap in order to help deal with it*" of course. ;)

Comment: Tim, can you please confirm [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/253243/what-does-the-front-page-mean/253245?noredirect=1#comment827266_253245)? Or was my initial assumption wrong?

Comment: @TimPost What happens when an answer has three of those flags?

Answer (score 3):

The front page is the main question list, the page at example.stackexchange.com that shows the most-recently-active questions.

If a question is downvoted enough, or picks up enough spam/offensive flags, it's removed from there so casual visitors don't see it.

Comment: There are many question lists on SO, such as "interesting","hot","month" and so on. Which question list does the front page mean?

Comment: @xshsinap all of them. It's removed from all the lists except search results. (e.g. you won't see it when viewing questions per tag)

Comment: @ShadowWizard I understand. Can I describe it like this? when a post accrued 3 flags (spam or offensive), it will be banished from all the question lists.

Comment: @xshsinap not 100% sure, asked now for official confirmation. :)

Comment: Still a work in progress.

Comment: @xshsinap you asked what "the front page" means and that's the question I answered.  Low-voted or spam-flagged posts are *also* removed from *other* lists.  If you'd meant to ask "what pages does the post disappear from", that wasn't clear.

Comment: @MonicaCellio I am sorry. It seems that the answer posted by Tim is more detailed. Thank you all the same.

Comment: @xshsinap no worries -- Tim gave a more thorough answer.  I was just responding to the comments here.

Answer (score 1):

Front page and home page are the same thing at Stack Exchange sites.

They default to their **active** tab on all sites except [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/) (which defaults to **interesting**).

For example:

- http://genealogy.stackexchange.com

[image]

- http://gis.stackexchange.com

[image]