# Difference between SO mobile and Desktop Sites

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, mobile-web

Perhaps a noob question, but here is what I see on my android device. By default I'm on "show: interesting" questions.

[image: SO mobile]

And I feel they are good fit for my taste. But I don't see this on the desktop site:

[image: SO desktop]

Maybe I'm not understanding the UI/filters on desktop well? At the moment it looks like I'm browsing on mobile, then trying to find the same questions on desktop version and this is annoying.

Comment: What are your favorite tags?

Comment: Just go to [Stack Overflow homepage](http://stackoverflow.com) and you will get the "Interesting" questions tab. It's not available in All Questions view, since it does not list all question, just the top 100 sorted by "interest level".

Comment: @Shadow Wizard: Thanks, i thought I was a noob, did not think it was that easy! If you put your answer as "answer" I can accept and upvote it.

Comment: @Tim: mysql, php, zend-framework, javascript, sql

Comment: And maybe someone from you guys know how to filter the interesting questions to only unanswered and interesting ones?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stack Overflow "interesting" view is available only at the [homepage itself](https://stackoverflow.com/):

> [image]

When you click ["Questions"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions) you're taken to the full list of questions, with the available sort/filters.

The "interesting" view however is showing only 100 questions, selected as result of a complicated formula taking into account your favorite tags, questions age, and more - this is [going through some changes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/253259/152859) these days so I won't go into this here.

Anyway, those 100 questions can't be filtered/sorted any further - to get Unanswered or have a different sort, just browse the full list, use the [built-in search](https://stackoverflow.com/search), or use [SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com/).